# How to attach a key to error attribute when return error

Tags: node.js, express

I am using nodejs and I return my response as follows:

```
res.status(503).json({"error": {"retry": true}}).end();
```

In the UI I see
[image]

However this is not what I want. I need {"retry": true} be part of the error attribute. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create custom errors in javascript:

```
const err = new Error("some message")
err.retry = true;
```

In the response you can just attach the `err` variable to the `error` prop like this:

```
res.status(503).json({ error: err }).end()
```

**EDIT**

I believe the default props for an `Error` object are name, message and stack.